# Photos do not show up in iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

When my iPhone 5c is connected via lightning cable the photos are showing up on one of my macs - which has El Capitan.  The photos do  not show up on another one that has High Sierra (and it did not show up earlier when that computer was on Sierra either).

Here is what is available:

[image]

What configuration is needed to get the photos tab?

Comment: Is iCloud Photo Library is turned on?

Comment: `iCloud photos` is enabled. Is that what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable icloud streaming photo on settings, otherwise you cannot see the photo menu below others. After disabling it you will be able to see all folders of photo

Comment: Please show or describe *where* is that setting. If it is on iPad then why is it working on the other mac to see the photos?

Comment: I found the following for on the iPhone itself .. not sure why then the photos show up on one mac and not the other: i was thinkiing should be a setting on the mac itself.  But will try it out anyways   https://www.igeeksblog.com/disable-turn-off-photo-stream-on-iphone-and-ipad/